# Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header in Azure Ratecard Apis in .net core

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, ratecard-api

I am trying to get azure rate card details by following api in asp.net core application,

**API:**

```
https : //management.azure.com/subscriptions/{Sub Id}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0044P' and Currency eq 'USD' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'
```

It was working earlier, but recently getting the below response,

> **Exception:**
>
> "System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check
>   the value of Authorization header..'"

Please find my code below here, The same code was working properly in .net framework console.

**Code:**

```
string requestUrl = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{Sub Id}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0044P' and Currency eq 'USD' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'"

string accessToken = "Auth token here";

var usageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

usageRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + accessToken);

usageRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

var response = (HttpWebResponse)usageRequest.GetResponse();                                            

var receiveStreams = response.GetResponseStream();

var readStreams = new StreamReader(receiveStreams, Encoding.UTF8);

var readData = readStreams.ReadToEnd();
```

Any ideas if anything changed on the Microsoft side or any another way to solve this exception ?

Regards,

Anand K

Comment: did u check the same api call using REST clients like POSTMAN?

Comment: see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/7423